# MYSQL INSERT CLAUSE USING PHP

Tags: php, mysql, insert

I am new to this website and also new in php..

I just want to ask on how to check a specific data or value in mysql database using the SELECT AND WHERE clause..

I have a table called websites.. And it has 3 fields namely id,websitename and ipaddress.

Sample content in the table

```
id   websitename           ipaddress
 1   www.google.com        12.1.1.0
 2   www.ebay.com          1.1.1.1
```

In my form I have a textbox where the user can input the website name and it has a button named get ip address..

To get the ip address of the website entered by the user I used the function in php called gethostbyname();

what i want to do is before gettip the ip address of the website entered by the user it should first check the database if the website name is already there. If the website name already exists, it should prompt a message cannot add but if the website name is not yet stored in the database it should get the ip address of the website and then it should be inserted into the table.

Please help I am so sorry I am a newbie.. Thank you very much in advance..

Comment: This is a very basic question. I think you should read some book before trying to do something more complicated.

Answer (score 1):

Basically for checking in database you need to do something like this:

```
$ipaddress = mysql_real_escape_string($_POST['ipaddress']); // get post data
//then query
$sql = mysql_query("SELECT id FROM websites WHERE ipaddress='".$ipaddress."'");

if(mysql_num_rows($sql) > 0) {
  //already exists
}
else {
 //does not exist
}
```

Yes of course you need to read some beginner tutorials for it.

Answer (score 0):

you must make a request on the name
You could use the "COUNT" SQL clause to count if there is already an entry.

If count != 0, you should add in the mysql.

If you are a newbie, you could use phpmyadmin to show concretly SQL requests.

hopes its help you

Answer (score 0):

1. Please visit http://www.w3schools.com/sql/default.asp. You can learn about `select` , `update` , `delete`
2. To save to your database with `mysql_query( "code sql ");`
3. Check data from database using `mysql_num_rows();`

Answer (score 0):

Try something like this:

```
<?php
// Make a MySQL Connection: change with your data
mysql_connect("localhost", "admin", "admin") or die(mysql_error());
mysql_select_db("test") or die(mysql_error());

// Get all the data from the table
$result = mysql_query("SELECT * FROM websites") or die(mysql_error()); 

if(mysql_num_rows($result) > 0) {
    echo "Can't add";
} else {
    $ip = gethostbyname();
    $website = $_POST['wesitename'];

    // Add into db
    mysql_query("INSERT INTO websites VALUES ($website, $ip)");

    // Print all values
    echo "<table>";
    echo "<tr><th>Site</th> <th>IP</th></tr>";

    // Print all the rows
    while($row = mysql_fetch_array( $result )) 
    {
    echo "<tr>"; 
    echo "<td> . $row['websitename'] . "</td>";
    echo "<td> . $row['ipaddress'] . "</td>";
    echo "</tr>"; 
    } 

    echo "</table>";
}

mysql_close();
?>
```